# Spring/Flex(online) to Spring/Air(offline)

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I've been working on a project that uses Flex + Blazeds + Spring. Now some parts of it must run offline due to connectivity issues. The problem is how to deal with the existing architecture, preserving it as much as possible, or at least how to create a solution not too much hard to evolve. 
I've seen many similar questions searching on the internet, but the most common approach is writing all code in actionscript(including business logic, access to database, transactions and so on), what I particularly don't consider suitable for the case. I'm thinking of using Jetty embedded in the application and some kind of embeddable database such as Java DB, so I could access my Spring services normally without any big change. Some workmates, however, disagree. They think that a web server running on a client's machine can lead to performance issues and a more lightweight solution is the way to go. Until now, no other solution came up. 
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Of course I do not know your concrete case, but in general I would agree with your colleagues. Especially if you wouldn't like to provide helpdesk services for your users 24/7. **Performance** may indeed be an issue if your users don't have powerful machines. I know Jetty is pretty lightweight, but on some older computers, you want to have as few processes running at the same time as you can.

But what I would be more concerned about, is the **maintainability** of your application. For starters, you'll have to get the whole stack **installed** on the users machines, which won't be easy. Once you've got that covered, you have that many **more points of failure**. Your application can now fail in the AIR app, in the local server, in the database or in the connection between one of those layers.

If you think the server you'll deploy on the local machines will behave a 100% in the same way your current web server does, you're probably wrong. You're not running Jetty or an embedded DB online, are you? Your users may have all kinds of different operating systems which you have to account for.

How are you going to push **updates** to your application? This is a pretty simple procedure in an AIR app, but it's going to be a lot harder if you have to also update the local server-side code.

I reckon in the long run it'll pay off rewriting some logic inside your AIR app. It will cost you some up front, but it'll cost you less in maintenance. I also don't think that the complete model should be rewritten. With these kinds of online/offline problems you can develop a strategy where you synchronize only the most important data. And if you dislike the code duplication, you can always write a generator that can take your Java model and create ActionScript duplicates.

Comment: I understand your point and I agree with most of your arguments. What I'm not sure is whether a code generator could help or not. We currently have Spring Services and DAOs, as well as Hibernate POJOs, in server side(java). It's not that easy to convert them to Actionscript, maybe even impossible. The database layer, for example, can differ substantially, because Flex(actionscript) still doesn't have all the facilities Hibernate and Spring provide. In order to attenuate performance issues when running offline,  is worthwhile writing different forms of the same logic in Java and Flex?

Comment: @user778258 It's true that Flex/AIR doesn't have an ORM built-in. And it's a fact that a generator cannot do _all_ the work for you, but it can get you halfway there (which is better than nothing at all). You don't have to do it all yourself: [ClearToolkit](http://www.cleartoolkit.com/dokuwiki/doku.php) for instance does a pretty good job already. In the end the decision is still up to you; I can only speak in general. But as I stated in my answer, I do think you'll spend more time on maintenance with the local server solution than with the duplicate logic.

Comment: @user778258 Something I just thought of: if you're able to mirror the server-side code on the client, that probably means you're throwing the entire domain model around. A more efficient way to work with Flex front-ends is to pass DTO's around that contain only the information needed by the client. This approach may also considerably reduce the 'duplicate logic' issue. And one more argument outside the tech realm: from a usability POV the client-side server is an absolute no-go for me (I've cursed enough apps like that back in the 90's), unless you can make the process completely seamless.

Comment: It's not a big deal using DTOs. The problem is how to manage the following logic:

Comment: if(connected) go to server, process everything and give me the result. Otherwise process everything locally and give me the result. Somehow transparent in a way that I don't need to create two separate windows for each situation. And as simple as possible.